Longtable goes beyond the right margin and footnote does not fit under the table
I am tying to generate a table within the longtable format using the following code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{array}


\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.6in}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} 

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}*{7}{c}} 
\caption{Summary Statistics: Covariates} \\
\toprule
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline (2011-2013)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{MDAPM (2014-2018)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{MDTCOC (2019-2022)}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Maryland}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Contiguous}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Maryland}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Contiguous}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Maryland}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Contiguous}\\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{U.S.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{U.S.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{U.S.}\\
\midrule
Female          &    0.619&    0.600&    0.595&    0.567&    0.550&    0.538\\
Graduated Highschool&    0.266&    0.295&    0.262&    0.279&    0.248&    0.259\\
Attended College&    0.241&    0.272&    0.231&    0.275&    0.226&    0.277\\
Graduated College&    0.426&    0.345&    0.453&    0.369&    0.468&    0.401\\
\textbf{Age Groups}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
25-29     &    0.036&    0.045&    0.030&    0.047&    0.041&    0.051\\
30-34           &    0.051&    0.055&    0.040&    0.053&    0.051&    0.058\\
35-39           &    0.060&    0.058&    0.049&    0.057&    0.059&    0.064\\
40-44           &    0.076&    0.067&    0.056&    0.059&    0.062&    0.065\\
45-49           &    0.090&    0.078&    0.073&    0.069&    0.064&    0.065\\
50-54           &    0.108&    0.099&    0.096&    0.088&    0.084&    0.078\\
55-59           &    0.113&    0.109&    0.109&    0.104&    0.102&    0.090\\
60-64           &    0.112&    0.112&    0.118&    0.113&    0.112&    0.105\\
65-69           &    0.102&    0.100&    0.123&    0.113&    0.110&    0.108\\
70-74           &    0.081&    0.080&    0.106&    0.091&    0.104&    0.100\\
75-79           &    0.059&    0.062&    0.073&    0.066&    0.078&    0.071\\
80+             &    0.079&    0.085&    0.092&    0.084&    0.087&    0.084\\
\textbf{Races} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
Black           &    0.200&    0.086&    0.202&    0.083&    0.213&    0.081\\
Hispanic        &    0.032&    0.065&    0.033&    0.072&    0.062&    0.082\\
Other           &    0.049&    0.050&    0.053&    0.055&    0.059&    0.062\\
\textbf{Health Plan}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
HAVE ANY HEALTH CARE COVERAGE &    0.928&    0.885&    0.956&    0.922&    0.945&    0.930\\
\textbf{Medical Cost}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\small{COULD NOT SEE DR. BECAUSE OF COST} &    0.091&    0.125&    0.074&    0.103&    0.073&    0.088\\
\textbf{Physical Activity} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\small{EXERCISE IN PAST 30 DAYS} &    0.740&    0.737&    0.752&    0.743&    0.769&    0.754\\
\textbf{Good or Better Health}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
\small{ADULTS WITH GOOD OR BETTER HEALTH} &    0.838&    0.806&    0.835&    0.812&    0.844&    0.827\\
\textbf{Health Insurance}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
RESPONDENTS AGED 18-64 WITH HEALTH CARE&    0.900&    0.837&    0.936&    0.887&    0.917&    0.896\\
\textbf{Obesity}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
OVERWEIGHT OR OBESE CALCULATED VARIABLE&    0.659&    0.646&    0.680&    0.667&    0.692&    0.685\\
\textbf{Physical Activity}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
Doing physical activity/exercise\newline during the past 30 days other\newline than regular job&    0.740&    0.737&    0.752&    0.743&    0.769&    0.754\\
\textbf{Medicine for High Blood Pressure}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
CURRENTLY TAKING BLOOD PRESSURE MEDICATI&    0.864&    0.843&    0.874&    0.833&    0.853&    0.827\\
\textbf{High Blood Cholesterol}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER TOLD BLOOD CHOLESTEROL HIGH&    0.426&    0.437&    0.432&    0.400&    0.418&    0.386\\
\textbf{High Blood Sugar}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
Had a Test For High Blood Sugar in Past 3 Years?&        .&    0.613&    0.679&    0.621&    0.602&    0.630\\
\textbf{Taking Insulin}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
NOW TAKING INSULIN&        .&    0.309&    0.306&    0.327&    0.318&    0.334\\
\textbf{Diabetes Education}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER TAKEN CLASS IN MANAGING DIABETES&        .&    0.549&    0.552&    0.548&    0.541&    0.536\\
\textbf{Cholesterol Check}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
Cholesterol Check Within The Past 5 Years&    0.888&    0.845&    0.935&    0.877&    0.937&    0.898\\
\textbf{High Cholesterol}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
HIGH CHOLESTEROL CALCULATED VARIABLE&    0.426&    0.437&    0.437&    0.408&    0.425&    0.394\\
\textbf{Heart Attack}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER DIAGNOSED WITH HEART ATTACK&    0.055&    0.061&    0.057&    0.060&    0.052&    0.056\\
\textbf{Coronary Heart Disease}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER DIAGNOSED WITH ANGINA OR CORONARY H&    0.057&    0.061&    0.060&    0.060&    0.055&    0.057\\
\textbf{Stroke} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER DIAGNOSED WITH A STROKE&    0.039&    0.041&    0.045&    0.043&    0.043&    0.042\\
\textbf{Arthritis}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
RESPONDENTS DIAGNOSED WITH ARTHRITIS&    0.333&    0.343&    0.373&    0.345&    0.342&    0.333\\
\textbf{Asthma} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER TOLD HAD ASTHMA&    0.123&    0.131&    0.136&    0.136&    0.140&    0.142\\
\textbf{Still Asthma}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
STILL HAVE ASTHMA&    0.710&    0.719&    0.702&    0.708&    0.698&    0.709\\
\textbf{Current Smoker}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
CURRENT SMOKING CALCULATED VARIABLE&    0.138&    0.165&    0.117&    0.148&    0.109&    0.134\\
\textbf{Any Drinks}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
Drink Any Alcoholic Beverage in the Past 30 days&    0.540&    0.508&    0.540&    0.514&    0.533&    0.519\\
\textbf{Heavy Drinker}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
HEAVY ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION  CALCULATED VA&    0.052&    0.055&    0.049&    0.057&    0.054&    0.062\\
\textbf{Flu Shot}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
SEASONAL FLU SHOT/SPRAY PAST 12 MOS&    0.491&    0.456&    0.503&    0.456&    0.568&    0.521\\
\textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
PNEUMONIA SHOT EVER&    0.376&    0.393&    0.471&    0.437&    0.447&    0.424\\
\textbf{HIV Test}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER TESTED HIV &    0.363&    0.294&    0.360&    0.306&    0.400&    0.337\\
\textbf{HPV Vaccination}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER HAD THE HPV VACCINATION?&        .&    0.087&        .&    0.122&        .&    0.206\\
\textbf{Shingle Vaccination}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
HAVE YOU HAD SHINGLES VACCINE?&        .&    0.157&    0.314&    0.301&    0.366&    0.375\\
\textbf{Flu Shot 65+}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
Flu Shot 65+ Calculated Variable&    0.639&    0.616&    0.625&    0.601&    0.721&    0.685\\
\textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine 65+}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
Pneumonia Vaccination 65+ Calculated Variable&    0.688&    0.702&    0.765&    0.742&    0.765&    0.734\\
\textbf{Mammogram}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
HAVE YOU EVER HAD A MAMMOGRAM&    0.833&    0.798&    0.848&    0.799&    0.806&    0.778\\
\textbf{Pap Test}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER HAD A PAP TEST&    0.948&    0.950&    0.955&    0.942&    0.943&    0.933\\
\textbf{PSA Test}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER HAD PSA TEST&    0.665&    0.639&    0.634&    0.588&    0.503&    0.500\\
\textbf{Colonoscopy/Sigmoidoscopy}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER HAD SIGMOIDOSCOPY/COLONOSCOPY&    0.759&    0.706&    0.778&    0.736&    0.758&    0.734\\
\textbf{C.O.P.D}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
(EVER TOLD) YOU HAVE (COPD) CHRONIC OBST&    0.072&    0.082&    0.081&    0.085&    0.072&    0.082\\
\textbf{Skin Cancer}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
(EVER TOLD) YOU HAD SKIN CANCER?&    0.083&    0.091&    0.103&    0.096&    0.096&    0.094\\
\textbf{Other Cancer}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
(EVER TOLD) YOU HAD ANY OTHER TYPES OF C&    0.090&    0.095&    0.109&    0.099&    0.109&    0.103\\
\textbf{Depression}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
EVER TOLD YOU HAD A DEPRESSIVE DISORDER&    0.160&    0.189&    0.170&    0.190&    0.167&    0.198\\
\textbf{Kidney Disease}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
(EVER TOLD) YOU HAVE KIDNEY DISEASE?&    0.028&    0.032&    0.038&    0.037&    0.041&    0.041\\
\midrule
Observations    &    35939&  1408186&    73926&  2176614&    63200&  1616354\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \emph{Notes:} Displays the means of the covariates and outcomes. The treatment periods are the Maryland All-Payer Model (MDAPM) and Maryland Total Cost of Care (MD TCOC). The contiguous United States (CUS) is the control group (includes the District of Columbia and excludes Maryland, Alaska, and Hawaii). College includes technical school.}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \emph{Source:} Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System, 2011-2022.}\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}

There are certain problems I can't fix despite trying numerous suggestions I've found here or by asking AI. The issues are as follows:

The caption (Summary Statistics: Covariates) is not displayed in the output.
The rightmost column (MDTCOC) is not printed in the output.
As you can see in the code, below MDTCOC, two columns — Maryland and Contiguous US- are supposed to appear, but the Contiguous US column is not printed.
The lines do not fit within the margin and extend beyond the right margin.
Lastly, the footnotes also exceed the margin.

I have attached pictures of the output for the first few lines as well as the footnotes. I would greatly appreciate any help.

\


welcome! use a p{} column rather than l for the long footnote so it can break lines e.g p{0.9\textwidth} or whatever is appropriate.

from the console: Overfull \hbox (808.6328pt too wide) in alignment at lines 10--122. that tells you a large chunk of content is not on the page.

If an answer is on spot for you, please make sure to mark it with a green check right under the upvote/downvote arrows. Also please upvote the answers that are fine (including the one you mark as "accepted"). Thanks!

As supplement to nice @cfr answer (+1) ...
For your table you may consider to use longtblr of tabularray package (instead of classic `longtable). Using it problem with notes at and of table is avoided, also it enable to automatic repeat caption column header at each part of table  and add information at bottom of table parts (except last) that table is continue on the nest page.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.6in,
            ]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\SetTblrStyle{remark}{font=\footnotesize}  

%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Summary Statistics: Covariates},
  label = {longtab:?},
remark{Note} = {Displays the means of the covariates and outcomes. The treatment periods are the Maryland All-Payer Model (MDAPM) and Maryland Total Cost of Care (MD TCOC). The contiguous United States (CUS) is the control group (includes the District of Columbia and excludes Maryland, Alaska, and Hawaii). College includes technical school.},
remark{Source} = {Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System, 2011-2022.}
                    ]{colsep  = 4pt,
                      colspec = {@{} X[l] *{6}{c} @{}},
                      cells = {font=\small},
                      cell{1}{even[2]} = {c=2}{},
                      row{1,2} = {c,m},
                      rowsep  = 1pt,
                      rowhead = 2
                      }
    \toprule
    &   Baseline (2011-2013) 
        &   &   MDAPM (2014-2018)
                &   &   MDTCOC (2019-2022)
                        &                           \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}
    \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-7}
    &   Maryland
        &   {Contiguous\\ U.S.}
            &   Maryland
                &   {Contiguous\\ U.S.}
                    &   Maryland
                        &   {Contiguous\\ U.S.}     \\
    \midrule
Female          
    & 0.619 & 0.600 & 0.595 & 0.567 & 0.550 & 0.538 \\
Graduated Highschool
    & 0.266 & 0.295 & 0.262 & 0.279 & 0.248 & 0.259 \\
Attended College
    & 0.241 & 0.272 & 0.231 & 0.275 & 0.226 & 0.277 \\
Graduated College
    & 0.426 & 0.345 & 0.453 & 0.369 & 0.468 & 0.401 \\

\textbf{Age Groups} &   &   &   &   &   &           \\
25-29     
    & 0.036 & 0.045 & 0.030 & 0.047 & 0.041 & 0.051 \\
30-34           
    & 0.051 & 0.055 & 0.040 & 0.053 & 0.051 & 0.058 \\
35-39           
    & 0.060 & 0.058 & 0.049 & 0.057 & 0.059 & 0.064 \\
40-44           
    & 0.076 & 0.067 & 0.056 & 0.059 & 0.062 & 0.065 \\
45-49           
    & 0.090 & 0.078 & 0.073 & 0.069 & 0.064 & 0.065 \\
50-54           
    & 0.108 & 0.099 & 0.096 & 0.088 & 0.084 & 0.078 \\
55-59           
    & 0.113 & 0.109 & 0.109 & 0.104 & 0.102 & 0.090 \\
60-64           
    & 0.112 & 0.112 & 0.118 & 0.113 & 0.112 & 0.105 \\
65-69           
    & 0.102 & 0.100 & 0.123 & 0.113 & 0.110 & 0.108 \\
70-74           
    & 0.081 & 0.080 & 0.106 & 0.091 & 0.104 & 0.100 \\
75-79           
    & 0.059 & 0.062 & 0.073 & 0.066 & 0.078 & 0.071 \\
80+             
    & 0.079 & 0.085 & 0.092 & 0.084 & 0.087 & 0.084 \\
\textbf{Races}  &   &   &   &   &   &               \\*
Black           
    & 0.200 & 0.086 & 0.202 & 0.083 & 0.213 & 0.081 \\
Hispanic        
    & 0.032 & 0.065 & 0.033 & 0.072 & 0.062 & 0.082 \\
Other          
    & 0.049 & 0.050 & 0.053 & 0.055 & 0.059 & 0.062 \\
\textbf{Health Plan}    & & & & & &                 \\*
Have any health care coverage?
    & 0.928 & 0.885 & 0.956 & 0.922 & 0.945 & 0.930 \\
\textbf{Medical Cost}& & & & & & \\*
Could not see dr. because of cost? 
    & 0.091 & 0.125 & 0.074 & 0.103 & 0.073 & 0.088 \\
\textbf{Physical Activity} & & & & & & \\*
Exercise in past 30 days?
    & 0.740 & 0.737 & 0.752 & 0.743 & 0.769 & 0.754\\
\textbf{Good or Better Health} & & & & & & \\*
Adults with good or better health
    & 0.838& 0.806& 0.835& 0.812& 0.844& 0.827\\
\textbf{Health Insurance}& & & & & & \\*
Respondents aged 18-64 with health care
    & 0.900& 0.837& 0.936& 0.887& 0.917& 0.896\\
\textbf{Obesity}& & & & & & \\*
Ooverweight or obese calculated variable
    & 0.659& 0.646& 0.680& 0.667& 0.692& 0.685\\
\textbf{Physical Activity}& & & & & & \\*
Doing physical activity/exercise\newline during the past 30 days other\newline than regular job?
    & 0.740& 0.737& 0.752& 0.743& 0.769& 0.754\\
\textbf{Medicine for High Blood Pressure}& & & & & & \\*
Currently taking blood pressure medicati
    & 0.864& 0.843& 0.874& 0.833& 0.853& 0.827\\
\textbf{High Blood Cholesterol}& & & & & & \\*
Ever told blood cholesterol high?
    & 0.426& 0.437& 0.432& 0.400& 0.418& 0.386\\
\textbf{High Blood Sugar}& & & & & & \\*
Had a Test For High Blood Sugar in Past 3 Years?
    & .& 0.613& 0.679& 0.621& 0.602& 0.630\\
\textbf{Taking Insulin}& & & & & & \\
Now taking insulin
    & .& 0.309& 0.306& 0.327& 0.318& 0.334\\
\textbf{Diabetes Education}& & & & & & \\*
Ever taken class in managing diabetes
    & .& 0.549& 0.552& 0.548& 0.541& 0.536\\
\textbf{Cholesterol Check}& & & & & & \\*
Cholesterol Check Within The Past 5 Years
    & 0.888& 0.845& 0.935& 0.877& 0.937& 0.898\\
\textbf{High Cholesterol}& & & & & & \\*
High cholesterol calculated variable
    & 0.426& 0.437& 0.437& 0.408& 0.425& 0.394\\
\textbf{Heart Attack}& & & & & & \\*
Ever diagnosed with heart attack
    & 0.055& 0.061& 0.057& 0.060& 0.052& 0.056\\
\textbf{Coronary Heart Disease}& & & & & & \\*
Ever diagnosed with angina or coronary H
    & 0.057& 0.061& 0.060& 0.060& 0.055& 0.057\\
\textbf{Stroke} & & & & & & \\*
Ever diagnosed with a stroke
    & 0.039& 0.041& 0.045& 0.043& 0.043& 0.042\\
\textbf{Arthritis}& & & & & & \\*
Respondents diagnosed with arthritis
    & 0.333& 0.343& 0.373& 0.345& 0.342& 0.333\\
\textbf{Asthma} & & & & & & \\*
Ever told had asthma
    & 0.123& 0.131& 0.136& 0.136& 0.140& 0.142\\
\textbf{Still Asthma}& & & & & & \\
Still have asthma
    & 0.710& 0.719& 0.702& 0.708& 0.698& 0.709\\
\textbf{Current Smoker}& & & & & & \\*
Current smoking calculated variable
    & 0.138& 0.165& 0.117& 0.148& 0.109& 0.134\\
\textbf{Any Drinks}& & & & & & \\*
Drink Any Alcoholic Beverage in the Past 30 days
    & 0.540& 0.508& 0.540& 0.514& 0.533& 0.519\\
\textbf{Heavy Drinker}& & & & & & \\
Heavy alcohol consumption  calculated VA
    & 0.052& 0.055& 0.049& 0.057& 0.054& 0.062\\
\textbf{Flu Shot}& & & & & & \\*
Seasonal flu shot/spray past 12 mos
    & 0.491& 0.456& 0.503& 0.456& 0.568& 0.521\\
\textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine}& & & & & & \\*
PNEUMONIA SHOT EVER
    & 0.376& 0.393& 0.471& 0.437& 0.447& 0.424\\
\textbf{HIV Test}& & & & & & \\
Ever tested HIV 
    & 0.363& 0.294& 0.360& 0.306& 0.400& 0.337\\
\textbf{HPV Vaccination}& & & & & & \\*
Ever had the hpv vaccination?
    & .& 0.087& .& 0.122& .& 0.206\\
\textbf{Shingle Vaccination}& & & & & & \\*
Have you had shingles vaccine?
    & .& 0.157& 0.314& 0.301& 0.366& 0.375\\
\textbf{Flu Shot 65+}& & & & & & \\*
Flu Shot 65+ Calculated Variable
    & 0.639& 0.616& 0.625& 0.601& 0.721& 0.685\\
\textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine 65+}& & & & & & \\*
Pneumonia Vaccination 65+ Calculated Variable
    & 0.688& 0.702& 0.765& 0.742& 0.765& 0.734\\
\textbf{Mammogram}& & & & & & \\*
Have you ever had a mammogram
    & 0.833& 0.798& 0.848& 0.799& 0.806& 0.778\\
\textbf{Pap Test}& & & & & & \\
Ever had a pap test
    & 0.948& 0.950& 0.955& 0.942& 0.943& 0.933\\
\textbf{PSA Test}& & & & & & \\*
Ever had psa test
    & 0.665& 0.639& 0.634& 0.588& 0.503& 0.500\\
\textbf{Colonoscopy/Sigmoidoscopy}& & & & & & \\*
Ever had sigmoidoscopy/colonoscopy
    & 0.759& 0.706& 0.778& 0.736& 0.758& 0.734\\
\textbf{C.O.P.D}& & & & & & \\*
(ever told) you have (COPD) chronic obst
    & 0.072& 0.082& 0.081& 0.085& 0.072& 0.082\\
\textbf{Skin Cancer}& & & & & & \\*
(ever told) you had skin cancer?
    & 0.083 & 0.091 & 0.103 & 0.096 & 0.096 & 0.094 \\
\textbf{Other Cancer}& & & & & & \\*
(ever told) you had any other types of C
    & 0.090 & 0.095 & 0.109 & 0.099 & 0.109 & 0.103 \\
\textbf{Depression}& & & & & & \\*
Ever told you had a depressive disorder?
    & 0.160 & 0.189 & 0.170 & 0.190 & 0.167 & 0.198 \\
\textbf{Kidney Disease}& & & & & & \\*
(ever told) you have kidney disease?
    & 0.028 & 0.032 & 0.038 & 0.037 & 0.041 & 0.041 \\
\midrule
Observations    
    & 35939 & 1408186   & 73926 & 2176614   & 63200 & 1616354   \\
    \bottomrule 
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}




You can use the warnings on the console (and in the log) to diagnose this kind of problem. Look for Overfull box warnings. Underfull warnings are also shown, but do not typically mean your content is invisible. It may be rendered badly, but it is at least on the page.
Here's a minimal revision which at least gets everything onto the page. The only real change here is to the specification of the column containing the overlong footnote, which is changed from l to p{}.
I also rearranged the headers and rules slightly so you get proper headings and footers for the table on each page.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.6in}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}*{7}{c}}
  \caption{Summary Statistics: Covariates} \\
  \toprule
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline (2011-2013)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{MDAPM (2014-2018)}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{MDTCOC (2019-2022)}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Maryland}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Contiguous}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Maryland}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Contiguous}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Maryland}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Contiguous}\\
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{U.S.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{U.S.}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{U.S.}\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \bottomrule
  \multicolumn{7}{p{0.9\textwidth}}{\footnotesize \emph{Notes:} Displays the means of the covariates and outcomes. The treatment periods are the Maryland All-Payer Model (MDAPM) and Maryland Total Cost of Care (MD TCOC). The contiguous United States (CUS) is the control group (includes the District of Columbia and excludes Maryland, Alaska, and Hawaii). College includes technical school.}\\
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \emph{Source:} Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System, 2011-2022.}\\
  \endlastfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  Female &    0.619&    0.600&    0.595&    0.567&    0.550&    0.538\\
  Graduated Highschool&    0.266&    0.295&    0.262&    0.279&    0.248&    0.259\\
  Attended College&    0.241&    0.272&    0.231&    0.275&    0.226&    0.277\\
  Graduated College&    0.426&    0.345&    0.453&    0.369&    0.468&    0.401\\
  \textbf{Age Groups}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  25--29     &    0.036&    0.045&    0.030&    0.047&    0.041&    0.051\\
  30--34  &    0.051&    0.055&    0.040&    0.053&    0.051&    0.058\\
  35--39  &    0.060&    0.058&    0.049&    0.057&    0.059&    0.064\\
  40--44  &    0.076&    0.067&    0.056&    0.059&    0.062&    0.065\\
  45--49  &    0.090&    0.078&    0.073&    0.069&    0.064&    0.065\\
  50--54  &    0.108&    0.099&    0.096&    0.088&    0.084&    0.078\\
  55--59  &    0.113&    0.109&    0.109&    0.104&    0.102&    0.090\\
  60--64  &    0.112&    0.112&    0.118&    0.113&    0.112&    0.105\\
  65--69  &    0.102&    0.100&    0.123&    0.113&    0.110&    0.108\\
  70--74  &    0.081&    0.080&    0.106&    0.091&    0.104&    0.100\\
  75--79  &    0.059&    0.062&    0.073&    0.066&    0.078&    0.071\\
  80+    &    0.079&    0.085&    0.092&    0.084&    0.087&    0.084\\
  \textbf{Races} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  Black  &    0.200&    0.086&    0.202&    0.083&    0.213&    0.081\\
  Hispanic        &    0.032&    0.065&    0.033&    0.072&    0.062&    0.082\\
  Other  &    0.049&    0.050&    0.053&    0.055&    0.059&    0.062\\
  \textbf{Health Plan}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  HAVE ANY HEALTH CARE COVERAGE &    0.928&    0.885&    0.956&    0.922&    0.945&    0.930\\
  \textbf{Medical Cost}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  \small{COULD NOT SEE DR. BECAUSE OF COST} &    0.091&    0.125&    0.074&    0.103&    0.073&    0.088\\
  \textbf{Physical Activity} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  \small{EXERCISE IN PAST 30 DAYS} &    0.740&    0.737&    0.752&    0.743&    0.769&    0.754\\
  \textbf{Good or Better Health}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  \small{ADULTS WITH GOOD OR BETTER HEALTH} &    0.838&    0.806&    0.835&    0.812&    0.844&    0.827\\
  \textbf{Health Insurance}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  RESPONDENTS AGED 18-64 WITH HEALTH CARE&    0.900&    0.837&    0.936&    0.887&    0.917&    0.896\\
  \textbf{Obesity}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  OVERWEIGHT OR OBESE CALCULATED VARIABLE&    0.659&    0.646&    0.680&    0.667&    0.692&    0.685\\
  \textbf{Physical Activity}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  Doing physical activity/exercise\newline during the past 30 days other\newline than regular job&    0.740&    0.737&    0.752&    0.743&    0.769&    0.754\\
  \textbf{Medicine for High Blood Pressure}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  CURRENTLY TAKING BLOOD PRESSURE MEDICATI&    0.864&    0.843&    0.874&    0.833&    0.853&    0.827\\
  \textbf{High Blood Cholesterol}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER TOLD BLOOD CHOLESTEROL HIGH&    0.426&    0.437&    0.432&    0.400&    0.418&    0.386\\
  \textbf{High Blood Sugar}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  Had a Test For High Blood Sugar in Past 3 Years?&        .&    0.613&    0.679&    0.621&    0.602&    0.630\\
  \textbf{Taking Insulin}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  NOW TAKING INSULIN&        .&    0.309&    0.306&    0.327&    0.318&    0.334\\
  \textbf{Diabetes Education}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER TAKEN CLASS IN MANAGING DIABETES&        .&    0.549&    0.552&    0.548&    0.541&    0.536\\
  \textbf{Cholesterol Check}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  Cholesterol Check Within The Past 5 Years&    0.888&    0.845&    0.935&    0.877&    0.937&    0.898\\
  \textbf{High Cholesterol}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  HIGH CHOLESTEROL CALCULATED VARIABLE&    0.426&    0.437&    0.437&    0.408&    0.425&    0.394\\
  \textbf{Heart Attack}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER DIAGNOSED WITH HEART ATTACK&    0.055&    0.061&    0.057&    0.060&    0.052&    0.056\\
  \textbf{Coronary Heart Disease}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER DIAGNOSED WITH ANGINA OR CORONARY H&    0.057&    0.061&    0.060&    0.060&    0.055&    0.057\\
  \textbf{Stroke} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER DIAGNOSED WITH A STROKE&    0.039&    0.041&    0.045&    0.043&    0.043&    0.042\\
  \textbf{Arthritis}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  RESPONDENTS DIAGNOSED WITH ARTHRITIS&    0.333&    0.343&    0.373&    0.345&    0.342&    0.333\\
  \textbf{Asthma} &         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER TOLD HAD ASTHMA&    0.123&    0.131&    0.136&    0.136&    0.140&    0.142\\
  \textbf{Still Asthma}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  STILL HAVE ASTHMA&    0.710&    0.719&    0.702&    0.708&    0.698&    0.709\\
  \textbf{Current Smoker}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  CURRENT SMOKING CALCULATED VARIABLE&    0.138&    0.165&    0.117&    0.148&    0.109&    0.134\\
  \textbf{Any Drinks}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  Drink Any Alcoholic Beverage in the Past 30 days&    0.540&    0.508&    0.540&    0.514&    0.533&    0.519\\
  \textbf{Heavy Drinker}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  HEAVY ALCOHOL CONSUMPTION  CALCULATED VA&    0.052&    0.055&    0.049&    0.057&    0.054&    0.062\\
  \textbf{Flu Shot}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  SEASONAL FLU SHOT/SPRAY PAST 12 MOS&    0.491&    0.456&    0.503&    0.456&    0.568&    0.521\\
  \textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  PNEUMONIA SHOT EVER&    0.376&    0.393&    0.471&    0.437&    0.447&    0.424\\
  \textbf{HIV Test}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER TESTED HIV &    0.363&    0.294&    0.360&    0.306&    0.400&    0.337\\
  \textbf{HPV Vaccination}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER HAD THE HPV VACCINATION?&        .&    0.087&        .&    0.122&        .&    0.206\\
  \textbf{Shingle Vaccination}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  HAVE YOU HAD SHINGLES VACCINE?&        .&    0.157&    0.314&    0.301&    0.366&    0.375\\
  \textbf{Flu Shot 65+}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  Flu Shot 65+ Calculated Variable&    0.639&    0.616&    0.625&    0.601&    0.721&    0.685\\
  \textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine 65+}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  Pneumonia Vaccination 65+ Calculated Variable&    0.688&    0.702&    0.765&    0.742&    0.765&    0.734\\
  \textbf{Mammogram}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  HAVE YOU EVER HAD A MAMMOGRAM&    0.833&    0.798&    0.848&    0.799&    0.806&    0.778\\
  \textbf{Pap Test}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER HAD A PAP TEST&    0.948&    0.950&    0.955&    0.942&    0.943&    0.933\\
  \textbf{PSA Test}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER HAD PSA TEST&    0.665&    0.639&    0.634&    0.588&    0.503&    0.500\\
  \textbf{Colonoscopy/Sigmoidoscopy}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER HAD SIGMOIDOSCOPY/COLONOSCOPY&    0.759&    0.706&    0.778&    0.736&    0.758&    0.734\\
  \textbf{C.O.P.D}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  (EVER TOLD) YOU HAVE (COPD) CHRONIC OBST&    0.072&    0.082&    0.081&    0.085&    0.072&    0.082\\
  \textbf{Skin Cancer}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  (EVER TOLD) YOU HAD SKIN CANCER?&    0.083&    0.091&    0.103&    0.096&    0.096&    0.094\\
  \textbf{Other Cancer}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  (EVER TOLD) YOU HAD ANY OTHER TYPES OF C&    0.090&    0.095&    0.109&    0.099&    0.109&    0.103\\
  \textbf{Depression}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  EVER TOLD YOU HAD A DEPRESSIVE DISORDER&    0.160&    0.189&    0.170&    0.190&    0.167&    0.198\\
  \textbf{Kidney Disease}&         &         &         &         &         &         \\
  (EVER TOLD) YOU HAVE KIDNEY DISEASE?&    0.028&    0.032&    0.038&    0.037&    0.041&    0.041\\
  \midrule
  Observations    &    35939&  1408186&    73926&  2176614&    63200&  1616354\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}

However, I wouldn't recommend using the table like this. For one thing, you end up with page breaks between row labels and the data to which they apply. Instead, I would consolidate the information in the first column so you have one row per variable/value. The capital letters are distracting and make for terrible line breaks. You could improve the latter a bit, but they typically do little more than repeat what the heading on the previous row tells you.
Presumably, you will be including the exact questions asked separately in any case, so the labels here don't need to provide half of each question. That's neither enough information if somebody has a query about what was asked nor little enough not to make the table cluttered with duplicates.
For a few columns, additional information is useful e.g. 'past 30 days' etc., but much of it could be dropped.
unless there is some pressing reason not to, I would also consider what is supposed to be most important here. Should the rows be grouped by diagnostic/test/question type? Should they be grouped by condition? Or something else? This is not my field, so I may be mistaken, but there is no obvious logic to the order of presentation. (Is it just the order questions were asked in? If that's crucial, perhaps it should say that in the caption?)

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

Switch from a longtable setup to an xltabular setup. An xltabular environment combines the capabilities of the longtable and tabularx environments. Set the target width of the xltabular environment to \textwidth, and change the column type of the first column from p to X. (This setup also eliminates any need to set the width of the p column by hand.)

Use the formatting capabilities of the longtable (and hence also xltabular) packages for headers and footers -- endfirsthead, \endhead, \endfoot, and \endlastfoot.

There are 6, not 7, data columns.

Change the column type of the footnotes from l to p{\textwidth}.

Don't increase the value of \arraystretch, but do use a lot more \addlinespace directives to provide more targeted visual grouping.

Use --, not just -, to generate en-dashes in various places.

Replace / character with \slash macro in order to allow linebreaks after slash symbols.

Why render the questions in ALL-UPPERCASE? It doesn't make for easy reading.





\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{longtable} 
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{geometry}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{array}


\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.6in}


\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit scope of next instr.
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} 
\addtolength\tabcolsep{1pt}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{6}{c} @{}} % 6, not 7, data columns

%% headers and footers

\caption{Summary Statistics: Covariates} \\
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline (2011--2013)}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{MDAPM (2014--2018)}
&\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MDTCOC (2019--2022)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}
&Maryland&Contig.\ US &Maryland&Contig.\ US &Maryland&Contig.\ US\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued} \\
\addlinespace
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Baseline (2011--2013)}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{MDAPM (2014--2018)}
&\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MDTCOC (2019--2022)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}
&Maryland&Contig.\ US &Maryland&Contig.\ US &Maryland&Contig.\ US\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Notes: Displays the means of the covariates and outcomes. The treatment periods are the Maryland All-Payer Model (MDAPM) and Maryland Total Cost of Care (MD TCOC). The contiguous United States (CUS) is the control group (includes the District of Columbia and excludes Maryland, Alaska, and Hawaii). College includes technical school.}\\
\multicolumn{7}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\footnotesize Source: Behavioral Risk Factor Surveillance System, 2011--2022.}\\
\endlastfoot


%% body of table

Female              &    0.619&    0.600&    0.595&    0.567&    0.550&    0.538\\
Graduated Highschool&    0.266&    0.295&    0.262&    0.279&    0.248&    0.259\\
Attended College    &    0.241&    0.272&    0.231&    0.275&    0.226&    0.277\\
Graduated College   &    0.426&    0.345&    0.453&    0.369&    0.468&    0.401\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Age Groups} \\
25--29           &    0.036&    0.045&    0.030&    0.047&    0.041&    0.051\\
30--34           &    0.051&    0.055&    0.040&    0.053&    0.051&    0.058\\
35--39           &    0.060&    0.058&    0.049&    0.057&    0.059&    0.064\\
40--44           &    0.076&    0.067&    0.056&    0.059&    0.062&    0.065\\
45--49           &    0.090&    0.078&    0.073&    0.069&    0.064&    0.065\\
50--54           &    0.108&    0.099&    0.096&    0.088&    0.084&    0.078\\
55--59           &    0.113&    0.109&    0.109&    0.104&    0.102&    0.090\\
60--64           &    0.112&    0.112&    0.118&    0.113&    0.112&    0.105\\
65--69           &    0.102&    0.100&    0.123&    0.113&    0.110&    0.108\\
70--74           &    0.081&    0.080&    0.106&    0.091&    0.104&    0.100\\
75--79           &    0.059&    0.062&    0.073&    0.066&    0.078&    0.071\\
80+              &    0.079&    0.085&    0.092&    0.084&    0.087&    0.084\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Races} \\
Black            &    0.200&    0.086&    0.202&    0.083&    0.213&    0.081\\
Hispanic         &    0.032&    0.065&    0.033&    0.072&    0.062&    0.082\\
Other            &    0.049&    0.050&    0.053&    0.055&    0.059&    0.062\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Health Plan} \\
Have any health care coverage &    0.928&    0.885&    0.956&    0.922&    0.945&    0.930\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Medical Cost} \\
Could not see dr.\ because of cost 
                              &    0.091&    0.125&    0.074&    0.103&    0.073&    0.088\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Physical Activity} \\
Exercise in past 30 days 
                              &    0.740&    0.737&    0.752&    0.743&    0.769&    0.754\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Good or Better Health} \\
Adults with good or better health
                              &    0.838&    0.806&    0.835&    0.812&    0.844&    0.827\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Health Insurance} \\
Respondents aged 18--64 with health care
                              &    0.900&    0.837&    0.936&    0.887&    0.917&    0.896\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Obesity} \\
Overweight or obese calculated variable
                              &    0.659&    0.646&    0.680&    0.667&    0.692&    0.685\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Physical Activity} \\
Doing physical activity\slash exercise during the past 30 days other than regular job
                              &    0.740&    0.737&    0.752&    0.743&    0.769&    0.754\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Medicine for High Blood Pressure} \\
Currently taking blood pressure medication
                              &    0.864&    0.843&    0.874&    0.833&    0.853&    0.827\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{High Blood Cholesterol}&        &         &         &         &         &         \\
Ever told blood cholesterol high&  0.426&    0.437&    0.432&    0.400&    0.418&    0.386\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{High Blood Sugar} \\
Had a Test For High Blood Sugar in Past 3 Years?
                              &         &    0.613&    0.679&    0.621&    0.602&    0.630\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Taking Insulin} \\
Now taking insulin            &        .&    0.309&    0.306&    0.327&    0.318&    0.334\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Diabetes Education} \\*
Ever taken class in managing diabetes
                              &        .&    0.549&    0.552&    0.548&    0.541&    0.536\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Cholesterol Check} \\
Cholesterol check within the past 5 years
                              &    0.888&    0.845&    0.935&    0.877&    0.937&    0.898\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{High Cholesterol} \\
High cholesterol calculated variable
                              &    0.426&    0.437&    0.437&    0.408&    0.425&    0.394\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Heart Attack} \\
Ever diagnosed with heart attack&  0.055&    0.061&    0.057&    0.060&    0.052&    0.056\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Coronary Heart Disease} \\
Ever diagnosed with angina or coronary h
                              &    0.057&    0.061&    0.060&    0.060&    0.055&    0.057\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Stroke} \\
Ever diagnosed with a stroke  &    0.039&    0.041&    0.045&    0.043&    0.043&    0.042\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Arthritis} \\
Respondents diagnosed with arthritis
                              &    0.333&    0.343&    0.373&    0.345&    0.342&    0.333\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Asthma} \\
Ever told had asthma          &    0.123&    0.131&    0.136&    0.136&    0.140&    0.142\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Still Asthma} \\
Still have asthma             &    0.710&    0.719&    0.702&    0.708&    0.698&    0.709\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Current Smoker} \\
Current smoking calculated variable
                              &    0.138&    0.165&    0.117&    0.148&    0.109&    0.134\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Any Drinks} \\
Drink any alcoholic beverage in the past 30 days
                              &    0.540&    0.508&    0.540&    0.514&    0.533&    0.519\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Heavy Drinker}         \\
Heavy alcohol consumption calculated variable
                              &    0.052&    0.055&    0.049&    0.057&    0.054&    0.062\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Flu Shot} \\
Seasonal flu shot\slash spray past 12 mos
                              &    0.491&    0.456&    0.503&    0.456&    0.568&    0.521\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine} \\
Pneumonia shot ever           &    0.376&    0.393&    0.471&    0.437&    0.447&    0.424\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{HIV Test} \\
Ever tested HIV               &    0.363&    0.294&    0.360&    0.306&    0.400&    0.337\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{HPV Vaccination} \\
Ever had the HPV vaccination? &        .&    0.087&        .&    0.122&        .&    0.206\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Shingle Vaccination} \\
Have you had shingles vaccine?&        .&    0.157&    0.314&    0.301&    0.366&    0.375\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Flu Shot 65+} \\
Flu Shot 65+ Calculated Variable&  0.639&    0.616&    0.625&    0.601&    0.721&    0.685\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Pneumonia Vaccine 65+} \\
Pneumonia Vaccination 65+ Calculated Variable
                              &    0.688&    0.702&    0.765&    0.742&    0.765&    0.734\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Mammogram} \\
Have you ever had a mammogram &    0.833&    0.798&    0.848&    0.799&    0.806&    0.778\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Pap Test} \\
Ever had a PAP test           &    0.948&    0.950&    0.955&    0.942&    0.943&    0.933\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{PSA Test} \\
Ever had PSA test             &    0.665&    0.639&    0.634&    0.588&    0.503&    0.500\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Colonoscopy\slash Sigmoidoscopy} \\
Ever had sigmoidoscopy\slash colonoscopy
                              &    0.759&    0.706&    0.778&    0.736&    0.758&    0.734\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{C.O.P.D} \\
(Ever told) you have (COPD) chronic obst
                              &    0.072&    0.082&    0.081&    0.085&    0.072&    0.082\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Skin Cancer} \\
(Ever told) you had skin cancer?&  0.083&    0.091&    0.103&    0.096&    0.096&    0.094\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Other Cancer} \\
(Ever told) you had any other types of cancer
                              &    0.090&    0.095&    0.109&    0.099&    0.109&    0.103\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Depression} \\
Ever told you had a depressive disorder
                              &    0.160&    0.189&    0.170&    0.190&    0.167&    0.198\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{Kidney Disease} \\
(Ever told) you have kidney disease?
                              &    0.028&    0.032&    0.038&    0.037&    0.041&    0.041\\
\midrule
Observations                  &    35939&  1408186&    73926&  2176614&    63200&  1616354\\

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}


Thank you so much. it was a such a big help!
